# "Did you mean" feature on a dictionary database

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I have a ~300.000 row table; which includes technical terms; queried using PHP and MySQL + FULLTEXT indexes. But when I searching a wrong typed term; for example "hyperpext"; naturally giving no results.

I need to "compansate" little writing errors and getting nearest record from database. How I can accomplish such feaure? I know about Levenshtein distance, Soundex and Metaphone algorithms but currently not having a solid idea to implement this to querying against database.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See this article for how you might **[implement Levenshtein distance in a MySQL stored function](http://209.85.129.132/search?q=cache:xHDB5crPdH4J:codejanitor.com/wp/2007/02/10/levenshtein-distance-as-a-mysql-stored-function/%2Blevenshtein%2Bdistance%2Bmysql&hl=de&ct=clnk&cd=1&gl=de)**.

For posterity, the author's suggestion is to do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION LEVENSHTEIN (s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS INT
    DETERMINISTIC
      BEGIN
        DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
        DECLARE s1_char CHAR;
        DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);
        SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0;
        IF s1 = s2 THEN
          RETURN 0;
        ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN
          RETURN s2_len;
        ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN
          RETURN s1_len;
        ELSE
          WHILE j <= s2_len DO
            SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1;
          END WHILE;
          WHILE i <= s1_len DO
            SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1;
            WHILE j <= s2_len DO
                SET c = c + 1;
                IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1; END IF;
                SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost;
                IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
                SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
                IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
                SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
            END WHILE;
            SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1;
          END WHILE;
        END IF;
        RETURN c;
      END
```

He also supplies a LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO helper method which will evaluate the ratio of different/total characters, rather than a straight edit distance. For instance, if it's 60%, then three-fifths of the characters in the source word are different from the destination word.

```
CREATE FUNCTION LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO (s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS INT
    DETERMINISTIC
      BEGIN
        DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, max_len INT;
        SET s1_len = LENGTH(s1), s2_len = LENGTH(s2);
        IF s1_len > s2_len THEN SET max_len = s1_len; ELSE SET max_len = s2_len; END IF;
        RETURN ROUND((1 - LEVENSHTEIN(s1, s2) / max_len) * 100);
      END
```

Comment: Also for posterity, this is code by Jason Rust which is based on code by Arnold Fribble which was, in turn, partially based on work from Joseph Gama.

Comment: D'oh. Somehow I thought I'd mentioned the author, but obviously I didn't. Thanks for filling in the gaps, @webbiedave.

Comment: Thanks for the UDF, it is very useful. But if I run a query like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE HAVING LEVENSHTEIN ('keyword', field) < 3(or so)" on a ~300k row table, it (obviously) takes ages to complete. I also tried reduce the rows search within (using WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(`field`) BETWEEN CHAR_LENGTH('keyword')-1 AND CHAR_LENGTH('keyword')+1 ) but it returns results in whopping 35 seconds :) Do you(or others) have an idea for speeding up this query?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/udf-compiling.html

> now i download the package from the mysql udf repository
>   http://empyrean.lib.ndsu.nodak.edu/~nem/mysql/

```
wget http://empyrean.lib.ndsu.nodak.edu/~nem/mysql/udf/dludf.cgi?ckey=28

ll

tar -xzvf dludf.cgi\?ckey\=28

gcc -shared -o libmysqllevenshtein.so mysqllevenshtein.cc -I/usr/include/mysql/

mv libmysqllevenshtein.so /usr/lib

mysql -uroot -pPASS

mysql> use DATABASE

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein RETURNS INT SONAME 'libmysqllevenshtein.so';

mysql> select levenshtein(w1.word,w2.word) as dist from word w1, word w2 where ETC........... order by dist asc limit  0,10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you [generate typo](http://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&safe=off&q=generate+typos&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=1bf98019f70a131d) variations on the query input.

i.e. hyperpext > { hyperpeext, hipertext, ... } etc

One of these is bound to be the correct spelling (especially for common misspellings)

The way you identify the most likely match is to do a lookup for each on an index which tells you the document frequency of the term.  (make sense?)

Answer (score -1):

Why not add a table column for storing the word in its alternate (e.g., Soundex) form? that way, if your first SELECT does not find the exact match, you can do a second search to look for matching alternate forms.

The trick is to encode each word so that misspelled variations end up converted into the same alternate form.